# shell script can't see files in remote directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, zsh

I'm trying to write an interactive script on a remote server, whose default shell is zsh. I've been trying two different approaches to get this to work:

**Approach 1:** `ssh -t <user>@<host> "$(<serverStatusReport.sh)"`

**Approach 2:** `ssh <user>@<host> "bash -s" < serverStatusReport.sh`

I've been using approach 1 just fine up until now, when I ran into the following issue - I have a block of code that runs depending on whether certain files exist in the current directory:

```
filename="./service_log.*"
if ls $filename 1> /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "$filename found."
    ##process files
else
    echo "$filename not found."
fi
```

1. If I ssh into the server and run the command directly, I see "$filename found."
2. If I run the block of code above using Approach 1, I see "$filename not found".
3. If I copy this block into a new script (lets call this *script2*), and run it using Approach 2, then I see "$filename found".

I can't for the life of me figure out where this discrepancy is coming from. I thought that the difference may be that script2 is piped into bash whereas my original script is being run with zsh... but considering that running the same command verbatim on the server, with its default zsh shell, returns correctly... I'm stumped.

:( any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not your answer but to test the existence of a file, `if [ -f <filename> ]; then` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when executing your approach 1 it is the local shell that expands `"$(<serverStatusReport.sh)"`, not the remote. You can easily check this with:

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> "$(<hostname)"
```

Is the `serverStatusReport.sh` script also in the PATH on the local host?

What I do not understand is why you get this message instead of an error message.